Enforce strict types while using generic with inheritance
I am trying to use in my project more strict type regulations. I want to use generics to enforce proper types. I've created an example (using AI) to make it clear and define my goals. I want to create a generic class that takes every animal. Next I want to create classes that takes specific animals for specific owner but i want to be sure that the owner must accept only animals that are specific to him. Moreover, I want to benefit from generics functionality.
class Animal {
    // Common properties and methods for all animals
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    // Properties and methods specific to dogs
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    // Properties and methods specific to cats
}

class GenericOwner<T extends Animal> {
    private animal?: T;

    setAnimal(animal: T): void {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    getAnimal(): T | undefined {
        return this.animal;
    }
}

class DogOwner extends GenericOwner<Dog> {
    // Additional properties and methods specific to dog owners
}

const dogOwner = new DogOwner();
dogOwner.setAnimal(new Dog()); // This is valid
dogOwner.setAnimal(new Cat()); // This will throw a compile-time error, but in fact does not throw


This code does not throw any errors.

In your example it doesn't error because there are no properties by which to distinguish a new Dog() from a new Cat(). If there were any, you'd get an error: https://tsplay.dev/wXdY1w. TypeScript is structurally, not nominally, typed: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

You simply did not implement the Cat and Dog classes, typescript compares object types by their structure and not their name, if you give the two classes different properties it will throw an error

Please [edit] so this is a [mre]. You just wrote "additional properties" but didn't actually put any in. If you do it, the problem will likely disappear and this is not reproducible. If you don't think you need to do it, then please [edit] to remove those comments about additional properties. In any case this looks much like a question about structural vs nominal typing so it might be closed as a duplicate.

From Your Code, Animal, Dog & Cat all are typically equivalent to {} which essentially makes the instance(s) of any new Dog, new Cat or even new Animal also equal to {}... Since Typescript is structurally typed; in your case: dog is always, always equal to cat! Just add some properties to any of the Classes and watch you terminal bleed...
